# How to prevent ajax request from going on server side on page size change when no records are available?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am using Kendo ui grid:http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

I want to stop my ajax request from going on server side on page size change when "No records are available":

From [Jayesh Goyani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/879020/jayesh-goyani) answer i have prevent sorting when "no records are available" like this:

```
$("#grid .k-grid-header .k-link").click(function (e) { 
                if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length == 0) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
```

**So how to do the same things on page size change**?

**Note**:I am using **Script for kendo ui**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. As per my knowledge its very difficult to prevent ajax request so when no record exists in grid then i have disable the pagesize dropdownlist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.902/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/products.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            products = null;
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                                UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                                Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true
                },
                columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
                ]
            });
            $("#grid .k-grid-header .k-link").click(function (e) {
                if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length == 0) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });

        });
        function onDataBound(arg) {
            if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length == 0) {
                $(".k-grid-pager .k-dropdown").find('select').data("kendoDropDownList").readonly();
            }
            else {
                $(".k-grid-pager .k-dropdown").find('select').data("kendoDropDownList").readonly(false);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Dont we have any click event handler on page size change like we have sorting click event handler instead of data bound event?

Comment: There is not any sorting related event available in kendo ui grid for more detail please check http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events

Comment: This is how i manage to fire event on page size selection but getting error on stoppropogation method: $("#grid .k-grid-pager .k-dropdown").find('select').kendoDropDownList({
                        change: function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    });

Comment: stopPropagation() is not available on dropdownlist change event. To avoid error you can use 'prevetDefault()' method but it will not stop the event execuation for dropdownlist change event.

Comment: could you please provide detail of 'other solution'

Comment: I mean is there any way to stop ajax request on this page size change  event handler??

Comment: As per my knowledge no other way to stop ajax request on this page size change event handler